# Query greater/less than using query#startAt/endAt

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using query#startAt and query#endAt to retrieve data from Firebase

The problem with both those API is they retrieve nodes with greater/less than **or equal** key.

Is there anyway i can query greater-than or less-than only? Or i have to remove the item manually when i've done retrieving

I am using the Android-Java Firebase API

Answer (score 1):

The operations are called `startAt` and `endAt` because they *include* the elements at the end points. To remove those "edge elements" you will either have to start at the next value/end at the previous value, or filter client-side.